# Quick C++ Query RE returning Strings from a function

Tags: c++, string, c++builder

I am updating my "C++" knowledge to the latest version using Unicode Strings etc..

Can someone please just confirm than creating a String within a function and Returning it is Valid? and it will retain the actual String data.

Below is a cut-down "nonsense" function, but is this "legal" and "safe" regarding creating & returning the String.? My testing suggests it is, but I would not notice if some memory was freed but not cleared.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

UnicodeString MyUTFToUnicode (WideChar *In);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   UnicodeString Test;
   WideChar In[] = L"My Wide String";

   Test = MyUTFToUnicode(In);
   wprintf(L"%s\n",Test.c_str());
   return 0;
}

UnicodeString MyUTFToUnicode (WideChar *In)
{
    WideChar wc[500];
    UnicodeString Out;

    swprintf(wc,500,L"Hello This is The Input String : %s", In);
    Out = wc;
    return Out;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to post a complete, minimal example. This does not compile for me, as I have no idea what this `Utf8ToUnicode` function is, its not part of C++. What library is this? And `String` is neither, so you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Advice: take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @kebs: `[ask]` expands to [ask]. Here's a list of other useful shortcuts: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @user4581301 thks! I still learn new stuff every day on SO...

Comment: Learning stuff is why I'm still here.

Comment: Thx for your comments.  I am using Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.3 to build my apps. "String" is an alias for their "UnicodeString" Type, and "Utf8ToUnicode" is one of their system functions.  I am unsure as to what is "standard" and what are their bespoke development libraries etc,.  I have re-worked the code to be a more basic version.